flutter build apk: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0
`When I run flutter build apk first time after cleaning project there are warnings in output. Second time there are no warnings
e: C:/Users/izgrablic/.gradle/caches/8.9/transforms/11d67339be20769aa23d66328d1f3d77/transformed/core-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/izgrablic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/2.0.0/b48df2c4aede9586cc931ead433bc02d6fd7879e/kotlin-stdlib-2.0.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/izgrablic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/2.0.0/b48df2c4aede9586cc931ead433bc02d6fd7879e/kotlin-stdlib-2.0.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/izgrablic/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/2.0.0/b48df2c4aede9586cc931ead433bc02d6fd7879e/kotlin-stdlib-2.0.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
build.gradle (project)
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }
    
    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    }
    subprojects {
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }
    
    tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }


build.gradle (project/app)
    plugins {
        id "com.android.application"
        id "kotlin-android"
        // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    }
    
    def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
            localProperties.load(reader)
        }
    }
    
    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = "1"
    }
    
    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = "1.0"
    }
    
    def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
    def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
    if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
         keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
     }
    
    android {
        namespace = "com.test.test_project"
        compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
        ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion
    
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    
        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId = "com.test.test_project"
            // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
            // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
            minSdk = flutter.minSdkVersion
            targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName = flutterVersionName
        }
    
    
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
                storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            }
        }
    }
    
    flutter {
        source = "../.."
    }


settings.gradle
    pluginManagement {
        def flutterSdkPath = {
            def properties = new Properties()
            file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
            def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
            assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
            return flutterSdkPath
        }()
    
        includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")
    
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            gradlePluginPortal()
        }
    }
    
    plugins {
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
        id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
        id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.0" apply false
    }
    
    include ":app"

